# Tar.gz and encrypt folders

Tags: shell, directory, tar, gnupg

I have a lot of folders I'd like to backup on a remote location.
I'd like to tar.gz and encrypt all of these, [if possible] in a single command line.

So far, I've successfuly did half the work, with

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec tar czf {}.tar.gz {} \;
```

Now I'd like to add an encryption step to this command, if possible using gnupg.

Can someone help?

Comment: Why, oh why, do you have to do it all in one step?

Comment: Because I'm sure it's possible ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't directly include multiple commands into `-exec` option of find.

On the other hand, you can easily iterate over the results. For example in bash, you can do:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
  tar czO "${dir}" | gpg --output "${dir}".tar.gz.asc --encrypt --recipient foo@example.com
done
```